# Flow returns wrong date value for the used expression

Tags: flow

I have a sample flow for testing purpose, see screenshot below. 
[image]

Compose Input expression:

```
addDays(startOfMonth(addToTime(triggerBody()['date'],12,'Month')),
sub(dayOfMonth(triggerBody()['date']),1),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Basically the thinking is using manual trigger when a date is given as input let's say 5/1/2019 then as a result compose should return 5/1/2020, so I am trying to add one year to the input date. The requirement is not to keep Month and Day number same as used in input date, only year value should be changed by +1.

For some reason its not working perfectly when input date is first day of any month.

1. Input Date: 5/1/2019--> Compose Output: 4/1/2020.--I want this to be 5/1/2020.

All other cases work fine, for example 1/20/2019 returns 1/20/2020. Its only the issue with first of the month it seems.

P.S: again the requirement is to increment year by +1 and keep month and Day value as is, can someone please help me with the correct formula.

Thanks in advance.